# DOMPDF: Frame not found in cellmap. O que ocasiona esse erro?

Tags: php, laravel-4, pdf, dompdf

Esse problema tem me perseguido há um bom tempo e ainda não consegui uma solução pra ele.

Eu desenvolvi um sistema, onde em determinado local, o usuário pode imprimir um relatório, que é gerado pela classe `DOMPDF`, no `Laravel 4`.

Parece que, quando os dados teoricamente ultrapassariam o tamanho do PDF (uma `<td>` muito grande por exemplo, ou sei lá o que é),  é lançado uma exceção.

Detalhes da exceção:

Classe  : `Cellmap`

Arquivo : `vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/cellmap.cls.php`

Linha   : `224`

Trecho do código onde a exceção é lançada:

```
function get_spanned_cells(Frame $frame) {
    $key = $frame->get_id();

    if ( !isset($this->_frames[$key]) ) {
      throw new DOMPDF_Exception("Frame not found in cellmap");
    }
}
```

Na `view` que é carregado pelo `DOMPDF`, estão os dados que desejo exibir no PDF, listados numa tabela HTML.

**NOTA**: Os dados da exceção não é o arquivo que eu estou trabalhando, mas sim o código-fonte da biblioteca DOMPDF.

Comment: Parece ser uma falha antiga, desde 2009. Já tentou seguir esses [passos](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=61#c21)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já enfrentei esse problema, há muito tempo não utilizo o `DOMPDF` mas no meu caso o problema era uma incompatibilidade com o `border-collapse` da tabela. Ao que parece nesse ticket é que o problema ainda persiste https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/657 desde 2013.

Também já tive problema com elementos com conteúdo muito grande como você descreveu, o que fiz para contornar nesses casos foi forçar uma quebra de página.

Para forçar uma quebra você deve utilizar um dos valores reconhecidos pelo `DOMPDF`, tentei achar alguma documentação mas infelizmente ainda não foi desenvolvido uma referência completa de todos os marcadores existentes. Eu conheço os seguintes: `page-break-inside`, `page-break-auto`, `page-break-after` mas acredito que existam mais tipos. Um exemplo de como usar seria dessa forma:

```
<table>
  <tr style="page-break-after:always;"></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Amigo, como você "forçou a quebra de página"? Eu removi o `border-collapse` e isso funcionou por um tempo. Agora, porém, já não funciona mais!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters atualizei a resposta.

Comment: O `page-break-after` não funcionou na `<td>`, mas funcionou  nos elementos que se tratava de rodapés e mensagens no PDF que eu estava gerando. Muito obrigado pela dica. Quebrei a cabeça, mas foi só insistir o pouco, que deu certo. Só espero que o problema não persista!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters legal, boa sorte em seus projetos. abraço

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso era que umas das tabelas que havia na minha página estava sem o tr encapsulando as tds. Depois de corrigir isso funcionou corretamente :)

antes:

```
    <table class="boxes">
        <th>Necessidade</th>
        <th>Área</th>
        <th>Cursos utilizados como base</th>
      ...
    </table>
```

Depois:

```
<table class="boxes">
   <tr>
    <th>Necessidade</th>
    <th>Área</th>
    <th>Cursos utilizados como base</th>
   </tr>
  ...
</table>
```