# Gerar um pdf de uma tabela em html e php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Basicamente tenho 3 tabelas , estou fazendo uma espécie de inner join em php kk e gerando uma nova tabela com os dados q eu quero ,tem como transformar essa tabela em pdf ?

`

```
<table>

                            <th>Nome do Aluno</th>
                            <th>Nome do Curso</th>
                            <th>Nome do Professor</th>

<?php

                $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","36398020","flex");
                $a=mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) from ALUNO");
                $res=mysqli_fetch_array($a);
                echo $res[0];

                    $f=$res[0];
                    $f+=10;
                    $nomeAluno=array();
                    $alunoCursoId=array();
                    $nomeCurso=array();
                    $nomeProfessor=array();

                    for($a=0;$a<=$f;$a++){
                        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select NOME_ALUNO from ALUNO where ID_ALUNO=$a;");
                        $n=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
                        $nome[$a]=$n[0];

                        $query=mysqli_query($con,"select ALUNO_CURSO_ID from ALUNO where ID_ALUNO=$a;");
                        $we=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                        $alunoCursoId[$a]=$we[0];

                        $sql1=mysqli_query($con,"select NOME_CURSO from CURSO where ID_CURSO='$alunoCursoId[$a]';");
                        $n1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);
                        $nomeCurso[$a]=$n1[0];



                        $sql2=mysqli_query($con,"select NOME_PROFESSOR from PROFESSOR where ID_PROFESSOR='$alunoCursoId[$a]';");
                        $n2=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2);
                        $nomeProfessor[$a]=$n2[0];




                        echo $table="       
                            <tr>
                                <td>$nome[$a]</td>
                                <td>$nomeCurso[$a]</td>
                                <td>$nomeProfessor[$a]</td>
                            <tr>

                        ";
                    }
                    ?>
</table>

        <A href=pf.php>PDF</A>

</body>

<?php 
        echo $table;
?>

</html>
```

`

O link aponta para este código

`

```
                          <?php   
            $con=mysqli_connect     

                         ( "localhost","root","36398020","flex");

            use Dompdf\Dompdf;
            require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
            $dompdf=new DOMPDF();

            $html=file_get_contents(pdf.php);

            $dompdf->load_html($html);
            $dompdf->render();
            $dompdf->stream(
                " ".$html."",
                array("attachment"=>false )
            );



            ?>`
```

Comment: Insere o código que você já tem. Existem algumas bibliotecas que fazem isso.

Comment: Estou tentando o dompdf mas acaba em erro

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta e insira os erros que são exibidos. Só assim alguém poderá te ajudar.

Comment: Qual o erro é produzido?

Comment: O PDF simplesmente não abre.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está usando o `file_get_contents`.

Essa função, pega o que está escrito dentro do conteúdo, isso significa que, neste caso ele pega um monte de códigos `php` que estão escritos. Ele não faz a consulta no banco de dados, por exemplo...

O que você pode fazer é usar um `buffer` de saída para armazenar temporariamente esses dados que são gerados e depois usá-los no `Dompdf`. Assim:

```
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    require_once'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();

    $html = ""; // html que será usado

    /*
        A partir daqui inicia o buffer
    */
    ob_start();  // inicio
    include "pdf.php"; // roda o arquivo

    // tudo o que foi gerado até agora, salva na variável $html
    $html .= ob_get_contents(); 

    ob_end_clean(); // joga fora o buffer

    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream();
```

Comment: Acontece os seguintes erros:                                                                                                                        ) Fatal error: Uncaught Dompdf\Exception: Frame not found in cellmap in C:\wamp64\www\Flex\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php on line 350
( ! ) Dompdf\Exception: Frame not found in cellmap in C:\wamp64\www\Flex\dompdf\src\Cellmap.php on line 350

Comment: @GuilhermeCarvalho dá uma olhada > https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51683/15361

Comment: Isso ai é um erro do seu HTML. Ai já outro problema que você precisa vasculhar...